# Two interdependant command line options with CommandLineUtils

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line-arguments, commandlineutils

I'm updating a project that uses [CommandLineUtils](https://github.com/natemcmaster/CommandLineUtils) to parse command line options. The options are defined by taking the `CommandLineApplication` and calling `cmd.Option()` on it, not with the options as properties in a class. For example:

```
public void Configure(CommandLineApplication cmd)
{
  var aOpt = cmd.Option("-a", "Option A", CommandOptionType.SingleValue).IsRequired();

  var bOpt = cmd.Option("-b", "Option B", CommandOptionType.SingleValue);

  cmd.Command("subCommand1", subcmd =>
  {
    var cOpt = subcmd.Option("-c", "Option C", CommandOptionType.SingleValue).IsRequired();
    var dOpt = subcmd.Option("-d", "Option D", CommandOptionType.SingleValue).IsRequired();
  });

  cmd.Command("subCommand2", subcmd =>
  {
    var fOpt = subcmd.Option("-f", "Option F", CommandOptionType.SingleValue).IsRequired();
  });
}
```

I'm adding a case where one of two options are required but not both. For example, if those two options are `-a` and `-c` then:

These are valid option sets:

> cmd -a

or

> cmd -c

These are not valid option sets:

> cmd -a -b

or

> cmd

How can I specify that two options are related such that at least one of them is required? I know about `.IsRequired()` but that looks inflexible.

(My case is a little more complicated in that either `-c` is required, or `-a -d` are required together)

Comment: Looks like this uses the standard modelvalidation from the DataAnnotations namespace in the framework. In that case you can use the [CustomValidationAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute?view=net-7.0) and implement a method for your cross property validation. An [example](https://medium.com/@mirzafarrukh13/custom-validation-with-data-annotations-1d4ca4130270)

Comment: I think what's throwing me off is I don't have a class with options as properties that I could apply a `CustomValidation` attribute to. I do have a `CommandLineApplication` where options are added with `cmd.Option()`. I'm sure I could set `cmd.Validators` but I haven't found documentation on using it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Custom validation can be added to a command by adding an `ICommandValidator` to `cmd.Validators`.

```
cmd.Validators.Add(new MyCommandValidator());

...

private class MyCommandValidator: ICommandValidator
{
  public ValidationResult GetValidationResult(CommandLineApplication command, ValidationContext context)
  {
    return ValidationResult.Success;
  }
}
```

In the example question there is a command with subcommands. This validator can check which command is being processed with `command.Name` if it is added to multiple commands. But it will only execute for the commands it is added to.

```
if (command.Name == "subCommand1") { ... }
```

To access the options use `cmd.GetOptions()`. This will provide a list of all available options, and include their values. `cmd.Options` can also be accessed, but is limited to the options specified by the user.

A specific option can be looked up by the `ShortName` or `LongName`.

```
var aOpt = command.GetOptions().First(o => o.ShortName == "a");
```

`HasValue()` or `Value()` can be used to see what options are set and whether they have a value set by the user. If the options are invalid return a `new ValidationResult("Custom error");`

Putting it all together:

```
// In subCommand1 definition
subcmd.Validators.Add(new MyCommandValidator());
...

private class MyCommandValidator: ICommandValidator
{
  public ValidationResult GetValidationResult(CommandLineApplication command, ValidationContext context)
  {
    var allOpts = command.GetOptions();
    var aOpt = allOpts.First(o => o.ShortName = "a");
    var cOpt = allOpts.First(o => o.ShortName = "c");
    var dOpt = allOpts.First(o => o.ShortName = "d");

    // Either -a or -c is required
    if (!cOpt.HasValue())
    {
      if (!aOpt.HasValue())
      {
        return new ValidationResult("Either -a or -c is required.");
      }

      // If -a is provided, -d is required
      aOpt.IsRequired();
      dOpt.IsRequired();
    }
    // If -c is provided, -a and -d are not allowed
    else if (aOpt.HasValue() || dOpt.HasValue())
    {
      return new ValidationResult($"{cOpt.LongName} should not be used with {aOpt.LongName} or {dOpt.LongName}.");
    }
   
    // Options are valid 
    return ValidationResult.Success;
  }
}
```

Note, if subCommand2 doesn't have complex validation and `-a` is always required, it is enough to add `aOpt.IsRequired()` in it's command definition.